# Entity Framework Core Stored Procedure returns -1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I created a simple sql server stored procedure that just sum two integer parameters as

```
create procedure sum(@a int, @b int)
as
select @a+@b ;
```

with the help of EF Core Power tools on my webAPI(.net core 6) I did a Reverse Engineer of a database.

then I just made controller method call this stored procedure, but it returns -1 to t variable

```
var t = await _context.GetProcedures().sumAsync(8, 9); 
Debug.WriteLine("t: " + t);
```

Someone have any clue about this issue?

Comment: Please share you stored procedure..

Comment: And share the code that was scaffolded for it with EF Core Power Tools.  Stored procedures "return" an integer return value, output a  rowcount, and can send result sets to the client.  You _want_ the resultset, but are apparently getting the rowcount.

Comment: @ErikEJ the Stored Procedure is right up there... It is called sum. Didn't you see it?

Comment: I see it. I will have a closer look

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to return a result in code, your result column must have s name, otherwise the tool cannot discover it.

```
 select @a+@b as result;
```

Comment: well... in the meanwhile I already had got it this way, but it created a sumResult class, and I was really interessest about to know why the first way didnt work, because in no time it was a restriction to be scafolded, but thanks anyway

Comment: Let me investigate again why no warning was surfaced.

Comment: It was a bug (an error should be logged) - I will publish a fix soon